# Требуется большой набор писем на португальском

Tags: java, email, search

Доброго времени суток,
Система которую мы разрабатываем разбирает тонны писем и анализирует их по определённым правилам.
Сейчас занимаемся имплементацией португальского языка и столкнулись с проблемой, что не хватает реальных данных для более точно анализа.
Нужен ресурс или место где можно этот набор данных найти. Может кто знает такие ресурсы?
Пример письма на англе:
`From: vasya
To: Olya
Sent: 19 March, 2007
Subject: known
CC: cc
BCC: bcc`

Comment: Гуглить буржуйские сайты не пробовали? В частности португальские сайты с любыми текстами, адреса, надо полагать, могут быть любыми?

Comment: @DaemonHK да, конечно пробовал гуглить. нашли несколько сайтов, типа https://www.mail-archive.com/ или http://nabble.documentfoundation.org/Portuguese-Brazillian-f2317324.html но оттуда нельзя выкачать письма